# Accessing computer highlight selection color through CSS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selection

How would I get the highlight selection color setting for a computer through javascript? Is there a way to get it through CSS? For example, my highlight selection setting is set to gold, so I would want to get the color gold.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get selection color through `getComputedStyle`. But seems it doesn't work for default selection style.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('pre');
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
  elems[i].innerText += ' ' + getComputedStyle(elems[i], '::selection').backgroundColor;
}
```

```css
.selection::selection {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<p>Try to select text below.</p>
<pre class="selection">custom selection color</pre>
<pre>default selection color</pre>
```